# Algorithm to divide into minimum number packages less than total price

Tags: algorithm

A customer ordered multiple products from a website. But the issue with delivery service is that a single order should be less than a certain amount. What is the best arrangement for minimum orders?

For Example,

Customer Ordered 2 Apple $2 each, 6 Orange $0.5 each & 2 Banana for $1 each. Max price per package delivered can be delivered is $3.

One of the optimal solution,

1 order is divided into 3 small packages as below

1. 1 Apple($2) & 4 Orange($0.5) = $3
2. 4 Orange($0.5) & 1 Banana($1) = $3
3. 1 Banana($1) & 1 Apple($2) = $3

If there are many optimal solutions, then dividing single type product is taken less priority.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Congratulations, you have invented (a slight variant of) the knapsack problem, a well known NP-complete (i.e. difficult) Computer Science question.  BTW, the only known way to find the best answer is just to exhaustively try all the combinations!

Comment: @MAP Wikipedia knows it as the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). If the prices are small integers, the usual solution is [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in-advance_algorithm), not exhaustive search.

Comment: @Gassa, OK my terms might be a little outdated (I took Rivest's algorithms course in about 1980).  But he's still reinventing an NP complete problem.

Comment: @MAP I also don't remember the names for knapsack variations, so had to look this one up. The more important part however is that the usual algorithm is polynomial in terms of N and sum-of-all-prices, which is often more feasible than exhaustive search.

Comment: @Gassa can I please get a sample algorithm.

Comment: @MAP can I please get a sample algorithm

Comment: @SubhrashisDas did you read the two Wikipedia links? If no, please do. If yes, and they do not contain the "sample algorithm" for you, define "sample algorithm".